# Powershell Script to get software Version of Adobe Connect & Zoom with GUI Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

Working on Powershell script to get adobe connect and Zoom Version in GUI. and getting hyperlink displayed. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Issue 1 - Both software version is not visible. Only one getting displayed either zoom or Adobe in output

Issue 2 - Unable to get Hyperlink for both row. Getting only for one at a time.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
    
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9)
    
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = 'PLT Readiness' 
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(325,225) 
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen' 
$form.Icon = 'C:\Users\C899414\Desktop.ico'
    
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120,150) 
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23) 
$OKButton.Text = 'OK' 
$OKButton.TextAlign = 'MiddleCenter' 
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK 
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton 
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)
    
    
$LinkLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel 
$LinkLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(81,110) 
$LinkLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$LinkLabel.Font = $font 
$LinkLabel.LinkColor = "BLUE" 
$LinkLabel.ActiveLinkColor = "RED" 
$LinkLabel.Text = "Ticketsystem" 
$LinkLabel.add_Click({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("https://service-now.com/nav_to.do?uri=%2Fincident.do%3Fsys_id%3D-1%26sysparm_query%3Dactive%3Dtrue%26sysparm_stack%3Dincident_list.do%3Fsysparm_query%3Dactive%3Dtrue")}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($LinkLabel)
    
$software = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label $software.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,50) $software.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) $software.Font = $font $software.Text = "Adobe Connect: $((Get-WMIObject Win32_Product |  Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Adobe Connect Application*'} |  Select-Object Version))" $software.Text = "Zoom: $((Get-WMIObject Win32_Product |  Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'Zoom*'} |  Select-Object Version))" $form.Controls.Add($software)
    
$help = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
$help.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,110) 
$help.Font = $font 
$help.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$help.Text = "Help:" 
$form.Controls.Add($help)
    
$help2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
$help2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,130) 
$help2.Font = $font 
$help2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$help2.Text = "Update From Software Center:" 
$form.Controls.Add($help) 
$form.Topmst = $true 
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and create a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As of now, there's a lot of code about GUI, and none of that is likely to be relevant to the point of getting version information.

Comment: For one thing, when creating the $software label, you should not try to cram all that into a single line, especially since there aren't even `;` characters in between to separate the different code lines. If you look at that, you are setting the .Text property to something Adobe, and immediately overwrite that with something Zoom. Also, it might be not the best way to check for installed software using Get-WmiObject..

Comment: Can you please help direct me for output.